# How can I stop a script from writing it's output to daemon.log?

Tags: linux, systemd, logs, daemon

I have a unit file that calls a script (myscript.sh), passing it a "start" command.  The script parses what is passed to it and if it's a start command, it runs a jar using this line:

```
java -jar some_directory/name_of_the_jar_file
```

I've setup java logging to write errors to a seperate file already, but the daemon.log file is still being filled up with java messages (both INFO and ERROR) from myscript.sh.  I tried changing the line to

```
java -jar some_directoyr/name_of_the_jar_file 2> /dev/null
```

But that does not appear to fix my issue.  I'm at a loss on what to try next.

Comment: Add a `1>/dev/null` to redirect `STDOUT`, as well as `STDERR`.

Comment: Which distro are you using? Where does `daemon.log` live? Is initialised (or even mentioned) in your script anywhere?

Comment: Running redhat 8.  daemon.log is in /var/log.  No, it's not explicitly mentioned, but the script is run through systemd, and systemd writes to that log.

Answer (score 0):

You tried

```
java -jar ${JAR_FILE}  2> /dev/null
```

which handles just stderr.

You want this, which sends stdout + stderr to the same place:

```
java -jar ${JAR_FILE}  > /dev/null  2>&1
```

You can always use `/tmp/debug.txt` instead of `/dev/null`
if you want to see what's going on.

Comment: In `java -jar ${JAR_FILE}  2>&1 > /dev/null` the order of redirection is incorrect. So `stdout` goes to `/dev/null` and `stderr` goes to `stdout`. see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: @davidt930, thank you. I stand corrected. Answer duly updated.

Comment: I'll try that today.  The messages in the daemon.log were all marked as "ERROR" which is why I only redirected stderr.